# How to convert a number to its exponential notation in Android?

Tags: java, android

There is a line, which contains a number:
String s = "12345678901234567890";
Also, there may be a floating point number.
How to display a number in exponential notation, if the obtained value of the number of characters greater than 10, and in normal form, if less than 10?

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal("12345678901234567890"); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.###E0");
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

See more about `DecimalFormat` in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)